# regarding chdir in perl, how do I get back to the previous directory

Tags: regex, perl

DIR1: a/b/c/d
DIR2: e/f/g/h

now I execute a Perl Script in DIR1 and chdir to DIR2(to use data in DIR2), after the script is executed I want to go back to DIR1. Is it default, if not then what command should be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. There are two different things I think you may be asking about. If I understand your setup, you do this:

```
$ cd a/b/c/d
$ perl stuff.pl
```

`stuff.pl` does `chdir("e/f/g/h")`. Now you want to go back to `a/b/c/d`. Correct?

### Case 1:

You want to go back after the script is done. Since the script is executed in a subprocess, when you exit the subprocess you will be back where you were before you started the script. Nothing special needs to be done.

### Case 2:

You want to go back before the script is done. In this case, you can remember the current directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# remember the directory
my $curdir = `pwd`;
chdir("e/f/g/h");
# ...
# return back:
chdir($curdir);
# ...
```

Comment: What is with those downvotes? Stepped on someones shoes? The answer does not look downvotey to me...

Comment: @DeVadder: No idea. The only thing I can think of is MicroSoft people frowning on `pwd` instead of the more portable `getcwd()`...

Comment: You shouldn't shell out to another program when there are good ways to get the information within Perl. It's as simple as `use Cwd; my $curdir = cwd;`. It should be noted that [Cwd](http://p3rl.org/Cwd) comes with Perl. If you can easily make your code platform independent you should do so.

Comment: @BradGilbert: Yeah. Thought to change it, didn't feel right ripping from chrsblck's code, so I left it as it was.

Answer (score 11):

You should use [`Cwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) before you `chdir` the first time....

```
use Cwd;

# get and save current working directory
my $dir = getcwd;

chdir("/some/path");
# do stuff

# now get back to original dir
chdir($dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    As per i get your question your purpose is first go to some directory like /a/b/c then  execute some stuff as per requirement then next step is go to another directory like  /e/f/g & execute some stuff.so i write below code as per your need.      

            $dir1 = "/home";
    # This changes perl directory  and moves you inside /home directory.
    chdir( $dir1 ) or die "Couldn't go inside $dir directory, $!";
    print "Your first  location is $dir1\n";
            #Execute your stuff in dir1 
    $dir2 = "/home/prasad";
    # This changes perl directory  and moves you inside /home directory.
    chdir( $dir2 ) or die "Couldn't go inside $dir directory, $!";
    print "Your second  location is $dir2\n";
            #Execute your stuff in dir2
```